# Keep only sublist in list if the 2nd elements are repeating

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

*Example*:

```
list = [['1', '13/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['2', '12/12/2016', [36, 46]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [13, 23]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['5', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['6', '07/12/2016', [32, 42]], ['7', '12/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['8', '06/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['10', '12/12/2016', [45, 55]], ['11', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]]]
```

I want to check all 2nd element of every sublist if they are repeating.
I want to keep the entire sublist if the 2nd element is repeating in another sublist

*Expected results*:

```
endlist = [['2', '12/12/2016', [36, 46]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [13, 23]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['5', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['7', '12/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['10', '12/12/2016', [45, 55]], ['11', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]]]
```

(08/12/2016 | 10/12/2016 | 12/12/2016 are the doubles)

I know how to keep doubles with a flat list `([x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1])` but how to do this in a list with sublists?

Comment: Why did you throw out the first element? `['1', '13/12/2016', [42, 52]]` has a `len = 2` list in its second position

Comment: why not just do '([x[1] for x in l if l.count(x[1]) > 1])' ?

Comment: @GáborErdős, I don't understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
lst = [['1', '13/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['2', '12/12/2016', [36, 46]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [13, 23]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['5', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['6', '07/12/2016', [32, 42]], ['7', '12/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['8', '06/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['10', '12/12/2016', [45, 55]], ['11', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]]]
endlist = [sublist for sublist in lst if sum(x[1] == sublist[1] for x in lst) > 1]
# [['2', '12/12/2016', [36, 46]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [13, 23]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['5', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['7', '12/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['10', '12/12/2016', [45, 55]], ['11', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]]]
```

Comment: Julien, Can you please help me with one more thing? What do I have to change in your answer if I want to insert only the first double string found?

Answer (score 1):

You can gather count information into a dictionary and then use that. This will scale nicely if the lists are large:

```
myList = [['1', '13/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['2', '12/12/2016', [36, 46]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [13, 23]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['5', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['6', '07/12/2016', [32, 42]], ['7', '12/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['8', '06/12/2016', [42, 52]], ['10', '12/12/2016', [45, 55]], ['11', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]]]

d = dict()
for subList in myList:
    if subList[1] in d:
        d[subList[1]] += 1
    else:
        d[subList[1]] = 1

doubles = [subList for subList in myList if d[subList[1]] >= 2]
```

You can of course replace `>=2` by `==2` if you want `doubles` to exclude triples, etc.

**On edit**: if you want to keep on the first occurrence of each doubled sublist, modify the dictionary so that it stores the index of each element. Something like this:

```
d = dict()
for i,subList in enumerate(myList):
    if subList[1] in d:
        d[subList[1]].append(i)
    else:
        d[subList[1]] = [i]

firsts = [subList for i,subList in enumerate(myList) if len(d[subList[1]]) >= 2 and i == d[subList[1]][0]]
print(firsts) #prints [['2', '12/12/2016', [36, 46]], ['4', '10/12/2016', [13, 23]], ['5', '08/12/2016', [42, 52]]]
```

**On further edit:** Here is a solution that removes subsequent doubles:

```
d = dict()

for i,subList in enumerate(myList):
    if not subList[1] in d:
        d[subList[1]] = i #stores first index

noDoubles = [subList for i,subList in enumerate(myList) if i == d[subList[1]]]
```

Comment: thank you John, I gave the "accept answer" to Julien because he was the first that resolved my question but I like very much the fact that I can I filter the doubles as in your answer.

Comment: @Reman Accept whatever answer best meets your needs. I see it as a question of scale. Below a certain scale the elegance of a 1-line list comprehension (as in the other answer) wins out. Above a certain scale, the fact that the two `for` in it makes it quadratic becomes important, in which case you need to gather the counts in 1 pass before you construct the end list in a second pass.

Comment: Can you please help me with one more thing? What do I have to change in your answer if I want to insert only the first double string found?

Comment: Wow! Great solution, but I still don't understand anything. So difficult these dict() solutions. I'm playing a bit with it to understand it better. If I want to obtain a list with all non doubles and only the first double this is the correct code isn't it? `[subList for i,subList in enumerate(myList) if len(d[subList[1]]) >= 1 and i == d[subList[1]][0]]`

Comment: @Reman That will work, but the way I construct the dictionary in the edited answer has the property that all index lists are nonempty, so testing `len(d[subList[1]]) >= 1` is superfluous. In this case, there is no point in ever storing more than 1 index. I'll add a third solution for this case.

Comment: Thank you very much John. That one is easier to understand. I resolved my question. I'm now trying to find out (just for hobby) to remove subsequent doubles but not to store the 1st index but the last index. (I know that the strings are the same but the contect in my textfile around the strings are not the same).

Comment: Easier than I thought: `for i,subList in enumerate(myList):
 d[subList[1]] = i     ////   noDoubles = [subList for i,subList in enumerate(myList) if i == d[subList[1]]]`

Comment: @Reman -- yes, that is the idea. If you overwrite previous indices only the last is retained. At this stage, Stack Overflow's comment software is starting to give polite warnings. about avoiding extended discussions --  If you have further questions post them as new questions.

Comment: John, yes extended discussion in comments. There is only one thing I want to try and that's to keep only to store only the last index of doubles (without the non doubles). Thanks for your great help. It was nice discussing with you. :)

Comment: @Reman You could always shoot me an e-mail if you have a  quick question later on.